# Selenium software testing Page Object Model

Tags: selenium, testing

I just want to know about the page object model thing. In an e commerce website if we have 100’s of products and each product has its own detail page.. Then do we need to have a separate page for each product to perform some action. Lets say I have a mobile page which have 15 products and whenever I click on specific product it will land on its details page. So do we need to create 15 separate class files, one for each page or do we have any other alternative for this.

Comment: Sounds to me like you'd want 15 separate instances of one class for those 15 products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ask yourself this question

- Is this 15 different product details page has same structure or different, I am not asking about page data (obviously it is different)?

if it's same, you just need one Product Details Page. If not you need to use inheritance to check how you can club related sub page in separate pages and create maintainable page object.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you only need one ProductDetailsPage class as the details and layout on the page will be generic ?